# Oracle SQL query to find the date in a format 7th JAN 2005

Tags: sql, oracle

Display today’s date in the following format: 7th Jan 2005.*/

Comment: Please don't tag spam; your title clearly states "Oracle" so there is no reason to tag 2 completely different, and irrelevant, RDBMS.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) [Documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-E118F121-A0E1-4784-A685-D35CE64B4557) contains a lot of examples for each format

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

TO_CHAR function will give you the desired result -

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddth Mon YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

```
Result - 19th Jul 2022
```